# How to Map Nested JSON to Class object using Auto Mapper in c#

Tags: c#, json, object, automapper

I have tried below code all works fine, But [sAA]->[code] & [sAA]->[Description] object gets null value , It would be helpfull if anyone please let me know if anything is wrong or missed in code .

```
public class CorporateRatesInfo
{
    public string Column { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string AgencyName { get; set; }
    public List<SaaCode> SaaCodes { get; set; }
}

public class SaaCode
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class CorporateRatesProfile : Profile
{
    public CorporateRatesProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<JObject, SaaCode>()
            .ForMember("Code", cfg => { cfg.MapFrom(jo => (int)jo["code"]); })
            .ForMember("Description", cfg => { cfg.MapFrom(jo => jo["description"]); });

        CreateMap<JObject, CorporateRatesInfo>()
            .ForMember("SaaCodes", cfg => { cfg.MapFrom(jo => jo["sAA"]); })
            .ForMember("Column", cfg => { cfg.MapFrom(jo => jo["column"]); })
            .ForMember("Name", cfg => { cfg.MapFrom(jo => jo["name"]); })
            .ForMember("AgencyName", cfg => { cfg.MapFrom(jo => jo["agencyName"]); });


    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {  
            cfg.CreateMap<JObject, CorporateRatesInfo>();            
            cfg.AddProfile<CorporateRatesProfile>();
        });

        //config.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
        var mapper = config.CreateMapper();       

        var jsonText = "{ \"column\" : 1001, \"name\" : \"CLN Industries Corporation\", \"agencyName\" : \"Murphy, Holmes & Associates, LLC\", \"sAA\" : [{ \"code\" : 247, \"description\" : \"Mechanic\\u0027s lien - Bond to Discharge - Fixed penalty - where principal has posted Performance and Pa\" }, { \"code\" : 277, \"description\" : \"Mechanic\\u0027s lien - Bond to Discharge - Open Penalty - where principal has posted Performance and Paym\" }, { \"code\" : 505, \"description\" : \"Indemnity Bonds - Contractor\\u0027s Indemnity Against Damages where there is a performance bond and addit\" } ] }";
        var jsonoObj = JObject.Parse(jsonText);

        CorporateRatesInfo dto = mapper.Map<CorporateRatesInfo>(jsonoObj);



    }
}
```

I expect the output dto.SaaCodes[0].Code = 247 , but it is null

Comment: `.ForMember("SaaCodes", cfg => { cfg.MapFrom(jo => jo["sAA"].Cast<JObject>()); })`

Comment: thanks @LucianBargaoanu . Works perfect ....

Comment: Just one more concern :
If i edited my class and Json string ,Then how to define profile for the added value 
`public class SaaCode
{
   ..
    public List<ExtraClass> extraCls { get; set; }
}
public class ExtraClass
{
    public string extrakey { get; set; }
}`
Json string :
`{ "sAA": [{ "code": 505, "description": "Indemnity Bonds - Contractor's Indemnity Against Damages where there is a performance bond and addit","extrakey" : "RandomValue" } ] }'